# What version of Grails to use for Multi Tenancy via Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, grails, multi-tenant, grails-2.0, grails3.2.0

Is it possible to implement Multi Tenancy in Grails 2.3.6 with Hibernate 4? Or can it only be achieved (or is it more advisable) with Grails 3.x? Any documentation material on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Grails 3.2.10 (last version) is **not** using the Multi tenancy mode by default. Nevertheless, GORM enables multi tenancy, when it is defined in the configuration. (GORM is the data access framework comes built in with Grails)

Here is a link to the [GROM documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#multiTenancy). You can see to the YAML configuration file:

```
grails:
gorm:
    multiTenancy:
        mode: DATABASE
        tenantResolverClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.web.SubDomainTenantResolver
```

GORM supports 3 different multitenancy modes:

> DATABASE - A separate database with a separate connection pool is used
>   to store each tenants data.
>
> SCHEMA - The same database, but different schemas are used to store
>   each tenants data.
>
> DISCRIMINATOR - The same database is used with a discriminator used to
>   partition and isolate data.

I hope that helps.

For more information please follow the [documentation of configurating and mapping domain classes.](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#_partitioned_multi_tenancy)

Comment: In short, because of GORM versions... Is it better to look for the implementation (of the multitenancy) with Grails 3.x than with 2.3.x?

Comment: Not all the features that works for Grails 2.3.X still works the same for Grails 3.x version. That is why I recommend to look for the newest version documentation when reading, but it should also be compatible with the Grails version you have.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go deep into the GORM documentation then.